# Refusing to install 'module' as a dependency of itself

Tags: node.js, npm

Recently, I was playing with a gulp tutorial and had this error

```
Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
```

when executing

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the name of my own application.

In package.json, I accidently named it gulp

```
{
   "name": "gulp",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "tutorial",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "rmv",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {}
}
```

Make sure your app is not called as one of the dependencies you will be using.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you are trying to install the package from the path (or in the folder) in which you had created the package.. 
 Just navigate to some other folder or path and then try to install the package 
 It should work.

Comment: great....It worked for me