# node js build real time chat error

Tags: node.js, chat

I am creating a real time chat app using nodejs , but on giving the command `npm i simple-nodejs-chat` i am getting following :

```
D:\chat>npm i simple-nodejs-chat
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "simple-nodejs-chat"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install simple-nodejs-chat as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\chat\npm-debug.log
```

kindly help .

Comment: Did u referred this https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12884

Comment: Change the name of project in your package.json to something else than `simple-nodejs-chat`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refusing to install 'module' as a dependency of itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722067/refusing-to-install-module-as-a-dependency-of-itself)